# Bump function which $=1$ exactly on some compact set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

Given an open set $O \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and a compact set $K \subset O$, there exists a $C^\infty$ function $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,1]$ which is constantly $1$ on $K$ and is zero outside some closed set inside $O$.

Is it necessarily possible to construct a $C^\infty $ function $\varphi$ that has the value $1$ exactly on the set $K$?

Same question for $\mathbb{R}^n$ replaced by a smooth $n$-manifold, which I think would be an easy extension.

Comment: Does $$\inf_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus (A \cup \{x \})}\exp \left({-\frac{\inf_{y \in K}\lVert x - y \rVert}{\lVert x - z \rVert}}\right)$$

work? When $A$ is some closed set inside $O$ with $K \subset A$ and +extra.